# Mapbox gl js - How to add multiple layers to Map.on Event listener

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am trying to add multiple layers at once to an event listener.  I am creating popups with information to be displayed upon the user's click.  Right now I have working code, loading layer1, then displaying the features of layer1 upon the user's click.  I would like to add multiple layers at once.

ex:
layers:['layer1','layer2','etc']

Right now I am just copying the following for each layer, but it seems inefficient.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
map.on('click', (event) => {
const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(event.point, {
    layers: ['layer1'] 
  });
  if (!features.length) {
    return;
  }
  const feature = features[0];

 /* 
    Create a popup, specify its options 
    and properties, and add it to the map.
  */
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
  .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
  .setHTML(
    `<h3>${feature.properties.Places}</h3><p>${feature.properties.Addresses}</p>`
  )
  .addTo(map);
});


map.on('click', (event) => {
const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(event.point, {
    layers: ['layer2'] 
  });
  if (!features.length) {
    return;
  }
  const feature = features[0];

 /* 
    Create a popup, specify its options 
    and properties, and add it to the map.
  */
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
  .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
  .setHTML(
    `<h3>${feature.properties.Places}</h3><p>${feature.properties.Addresses}</p>`
  )
  .addTo(map);
});
```

I tried adding multiple layers layers:['layer1','layer2','etc']  thinking this would work, but the map won't load.

Comment: Also I would like to be able to insert hyperlinks as properties of each feature, however when I uploaded my .csv containing these links to my Layer, they showed up as plaintext and not the url underlying the hyperlink.  What's the best way to have this functionality where a user can click an icon, view it's info, and click an external link to direct them to a website?

Comment: That should work, the syntax looks right. You could also just query all the features and filter them by the layer ID.